# Boost: MacOSX binaries for Boost

Tags: macos, boost, universal-binary

Are there any MacOSX universal binaries (at least i386/ppc for >=macosx10.3) for Boost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install Boost on Mac by using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

Once MacPorts is installed you just have to issue the following command:

> `$ sudo port install boost`*`+universal`*

You can also ask MacPorts to build [binary packages](http://guide.macports.org/#using.binaries.binary-packages) for you by either issuing:

```
$ port pkg pstree
```

or

```
$ port dmg pstree
```

The pkg or dmg files will be placed in a subfolder of `/opt/local/var/macports/build`

---

EDIT: nowadays you can install it with [`brew`](http://brew.sh/)

```
$ brew install boost
```

see also

```
$ brew info boost
```

Comment: I need Universal binaries to redistribute it.

Comment: How can I be sure that I can redistribute this variant without problems? And that MacPorts doesn't install other dependencies?

Comment: I think MacPorts has no reason to make boost depend on something special. I don't think there is a problem redistributing what's built by MacPorts, just test your package on several OSX versions to make sure of it.

Comment: Btw., does port compile itself or are this binaries? In the case this are binaries, can't I download them manually?

Comment: macports compiles packages and is optionally able to create binary packages, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed an addon for openframeworks with basically **pre-compiled boost libraries 1.57.0** for **i386** and **x86_64** which is on the following github repo:

https://github.com/danoli3/ofxOSXBoost/ (i386 precompiled on master)

Also compiled the x86_64 version for Universal 32bit/64bit for newer macs/osx. https://github.com/danoli3/ofxOSXBoost/tree/x86_64

You can also build the library yourself (which will automatically download it from source forge for the tagged version (1.57.0) and compile and setup like the other branches. https://github.com/danoli3/ofxOSXBoost/tree/build-yourself

See the readme for more help:

https://github.com/danoli3/ofxOSXBoost/