# Error: boost/scoped_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory while using libkml

Tags: c++, google-maps

I am developing a software which uses Google Map database. I searched google and I found a library in C++ can do that - libkml. I've downloaded some examples code in this [website](http://code.google.com/p/libkml/source/browse/trunk/examples/#examples/xsd%253Fstate%253Dclosed), but when I compiled with this command: `g++ main.cpp -lkml`, it occured an error:

```
fatal error: boost/scoped_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
```

What is "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"? I try finding this file in terminal

```
locate boost/scoped_ptr.hpp
```

but there's nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the boost libraries from http://www.boost.org/

Depending on your OS there will be pre-built solutions that you can install. For example on Ubuntu you can do `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`. On Mac see this thread [Boost: MacOSX binaries for Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833653/boost-macosx-binaries-for-boost)
On Windows this may help: http://boost.teeks99.com/

Comment: well, you 're right. I've installed libboost, but when I compiled again, it had another error: cannot find -lkml althougth I installed the libkml with command: sudo apt-get install libkml-dev. I don't understand. I try to find this library but there was no where to be found. Can you help me?

Comment: `libkml` is made up of several libraries. Although I haven't used libkml myself, this [link](http://code.google.com/p/libkml/issues/detail?id=146&q=link) suggests you need to link with `-lkmlbase -lkmlconvenience -lkmlengine -lkmldom`

Comment: okay, I will check, thank you :). By the way, I have a question: Can I use directly Google map in my PC? I mean is it necessary to make a web, and the map is accessed by the browser or I can use [link](http://maps.google.com), export to kml file and process it?

Comment: how can one install `boost` on `Red Hat`  OS ?

Comment: @FäridAlijani please submit a new question with your specific problem.