# Error installing caffe model on Mac

Tags: macos, caffe

I am trying to install caffe model on Mac. When I run `make test`, I get this error. How do I fix it?

```
Hsus-MacBook-Pro:caffe HTS$ make test
CXX src/caffe/test/test_random_number_generator.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/test/test_random_number_generator.cpp:5:
./include/caffe/common.hpp:4:10: fatal error: 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_random_number_generator.o] Error 1
```

Comment: The error message indicates you're lacking a file from the `boost` library. Have you installed boost?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: boost/scoped\_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory while using libkml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480020/error-boost-scoped-ptr-hpp-no-such-file-or-directory-while-using-libkml)

Comment: thanks . but now the error is changed..PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
In file included from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:5:
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:9:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h' file not found
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o] Error 1

Comment: Are you following the OS X installation instructions at http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html?

Comment: The current error message suggests you're missing protobuf. If you follow the installation instructions, the libraries that you're missing (boost, protobuf) are installed prior to installing caffe, so you should not get these errors.